# Why Map record output=0 , even when I am giving output in mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I have tried a lot , but not understanding a reason why my mapper record output =0 . I want my mapper to read the lines more than once as I am working on big data and need the data on each line more than once so I was trying this first with small file(graph.txt) which contain --

```
   1,2,4,6
   2,10,3,7
   3,6,5,8
   4,7,7,9
   5,13,9,9
```

But as mapper deal with file line by line so there is no other way then that I first store all values in file when map() method is called first (n-1) times  and then do the processing in last map() method call. 
for each row in a file I am storing its data in a row array. And in last map method call giving output via output.collect() function.
Also I am using setup() method to calculate no. of rows in file ,as setup() is called once for each mapper. Here **As input file is small so only 1 mapper is called**.

I am stuck at this for a while and I am new to this , please give some solution.
Thanks in advance.
Here's the code.

**Driver Code**-

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;


    public class primdriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(primdriver.class);
        conf.setJobName("primdriver");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(primmapper.class);
        //conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(primreducer.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

       JobClient.runJob(conf);
      }
}
```

**Mapper Code** -

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

    public class primmapper extends MapReduceBase implements         
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        //private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        //private Text word = new Text();
        private int no_line=0;
        private int i=0;
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
            Path pt=new Path("hdfs:/myinput/graph.txt");//Location of file         
            in HDFS
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new                 
            InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
            String line;
            line=br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                no_line=no_line+1;
                line=br.readLine();
            }
        }   
        private String [][]row=new String[no_line][4];

        @Override       
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, 
   Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {        

            if (i<no_line-1){

                String[] s = value.toString().split(",");
                for (int j=0;j<s.length;j++){
                    row[i][j]=(s[j]);
                }
                i=i+1;
            }
            else{
                String[] s = value.toString().split(",");
                for (int j=0;j<s.length;j++){
            //row[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(s[j]);
                }
                for (int i=0;i<no_line-1;i++){
                    String a=row[i][0];
                    String b=row[i][1]+","+row[i][2]+","+row[i][3];
                    output.collect(new Text(a),new Text(b));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Reducer Code** -

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;


        public class primreducer extends MapReduceBase implements 
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, 
   OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException         
   {
        int a = 0, b = 0 , c = 0;
        output.collect(new Text("kishan "), new Text("sharma"));
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            String val[]=(values.next().toString()).split(",");
            a=Integer.parseInt(val[0]);
            b=Integer.parseInt(val[1]);
            c=Integer.parseInt(val[2]);
        }
        output.collect(key, new Text(a+","+b+","+c));
    }
}
```

**In console I got this logs**-

```
    [training@localhost workspace]$ hadoop jar hierarchical.jar primdriver 
    myinput/graph.txt cluster5
    17/04/07 10:21:18 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for         
    parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
    17/04/07 10:21:18 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
    17/04/07 10:21:18 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
    17/04/07 10:21:18 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    17/04/07 10:21:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201704070816_0007
    17/04/07 10:21:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    17/04/07 10:22:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
    17/04/07 10:22:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
    17/04/07 10:22:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201704070816_0007
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 33
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=6
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=361924
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=146
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=3
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=90240
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=31777
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=5
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=104
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=6
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=1240
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=196472832
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=775897088
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=177016832
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
    17/04/07 10:23:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     BYTES_READ=42
```

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is smaller than `no_line-1`, you don't collect anything. This condition always holds in your case, and that's why you are not seeing any map output records.

When you start processing the first record, `no_line` is already initialized at its final value (the actual number of lines in the input file "hdfs:/myinput/graph.txt").

At this point, `i` is 0. Then, when this if condition is met, `i` becomes 1 *in this specific mapper* (not at all mappers).* Then, `i` has the value 1 (in this mapper) and it must be still less than `no_line - 1`. It seems that your file `graph.txt` has more than 5 lines (I guess).

In summary, `setup()` is executed once before each `map()` gets executed at every mapper.

I have no idea what you want to do, and it seems difficult to understand from this part. Try to make it clearer and also update your question with more details, if you need more help. In the else statement, using variable `i` again seems very confusing, as it is not clear if you actually want to use the local `i`, or the "shadowed" `i`. Doesn't your IDE give a warning about that?

*This is a very bad practice, as you can't know which values `i` will take in each mapper, it depends on the data partitioning.

Comment: I have clarified the question now. I hope  it's clear now and please tell me what's wrong with this.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. Actually the value of i and no_line both are zero after setup() method has been called. So its never executing the if condition. Thats why no ouput is coming out of mapper. Can you tell me why setup is not working.

Comment: @KISHANSHARMA Because either there is no such file at this path (check loggers err messages) or this file is empty. This doesn't mean that the if statement is not checked. It means that it is checked, but the flow goes to the else condition, and then does nothing, since no_line is 0